# Reset i18next on user action

Tags: javascript, i18next

I want to reset i18next translations on my web app. I am currently trying this:

```js
// After user action:
i18n.init({
  lng: language
});
$('body').i18n();
```

But its not working as i expected. Translations who are inyected using [prepend] or [append] are being duplicated.

```html
<a class="landing-secondary-section-endlink" data-i18n="[prepend]landing-secondary-section-teach" href="http://..." target="_blank">Descubre una nueva forma de enseñar.Irakasteko era berri bat aurkitu.Scopri una nuova forma di insegnare.Descubre una nueva forma de enseñar.Discover a new way of teaching.Descubre una nueva forma de enseñar.Irakasteko era berri bat aurkitu.Descubre una nueva forma de enseñar.<span class="landing__link-underline"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing all translations first.